# unable to achieve the functionality to show records in same visual force page

Tags: visualforce

unable to show records in same visual force page
[image: show records in same visual force page]

[image]

hi i am having a visual force page when i save records it must save just below in same visual force page unless it redirect to record detail page.

Comment: Please edit your question.... It is impossible to understand your problem....

Answer (score 1):

```
public PageReference sendPage() {
   // .. your logic
   // .. your logic
   return null;
}
```

it will not redirect to another page..